# Migrating Google Accounts into Google Apps

Tags: google, email, google-workspace

My company wants to migrate all email and cloud work to Google Apps for Business. We currently have a Google account, however, with our domain appended to the user name. It's my understanding that Google no longer allows setting up accounts like this, and forces a `*@gmail.com` address.

So, in this case, we already use `webguy@example.com`. In a previous case where I have migrated to Google Apps in the past, if you set up your account with domain `example.com`, any existing Google accounts with that domain are either smitten or forced to choose new user names. We would like to continue to use `webguy@example.com`, but it's not as simple as exporting email, calendar, and docs, as we also have our AdWords, Analytics, and AdSense accounts tied to this username.

So ultimately the question is if anyone knows how to migrate this one account straight into the Google Apps for Business domain either before or once it's set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good luck with that one. The short answer is: No, there is no way of transferring existing Google accounts into a Google Apps for Business Account. I have tried. There's just no way.

You can transfer some data to your new Google Apps account or at least make it accessible from there.

Please see for yourself here, it's the ultimate Google migration list, well hidden in the documentation:
http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=de&answer=58582

Comment: I'll second this, I've tried. If you need to use both accounts simultaneously enable multiple logins in your account settings and use chrome!

Comment: So it looks like AdSense will be the little ruffian, then? Well, I'll try to convince marketing to set that up again.